# usage of perl find and replacement (regex) for a verilog netlist

Tags: perl, verilog

I am trying to develop a script which takes input of a verilog netlist and create a testbench for that, so when we connect test-bench to the main module by name we do somethin like this,

```
.a(a); .ext(ext);    etc etc.
```

now I have like 120 inputs for a bigger block like

```
 `in1, in2... and some arrays like [31:0] ext; etc
```

I want to match the pattern of .in1; and replace it as .in1(in1);

I am trying

```
 s/^\s+\.(.*)/\.$1\($1\)/g;
```

so it will check a string starting with space characters, followed by a single '.' character and then all characters, and replace it with the pattern shown in the statement line,

the complete code as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift;
open (my $fh , "<" , $filename) or die $!; 
open (my $pr , ">" , "D:/dump/testbench.v") or die $!; 

my @code;
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{   
    chomp $line;
    @code = (@code, $line);
}   
#foreach my $i (0..$#code)
#{  
#print "$code[$i]\n";
#}  
#   

foreach my $j (0..$#code)
{   
    if ($code[$j] =~ /^\s+\..*/)
    {   
        print "$code[$j]\n";
        $code[$j] =~ s/^\s+\.(.*)/\.$1\($1\)/g;
        print "$code[$j]\n";
    }   
}   

foreach my $k (0..$#code)
{   
    print $pr "$code[$k]\n";
}   
close $pr;
```

The replacement pattern does something like `.in1;(in1;)` instead of `.in1(in1);` and `.[31:0] ext;([31:0] ext;)`.

how to do it in better way?

Comment: The shown code is invalid -- there are four (4) `/`, which is illegal syntax. Then the `~` is unmotivated, and you capture an optional comma (possibly repeated), which makes no sense for the previous problem description. Can you please be careful and show your actual code?

Comment: Also, CPAN has several Verilog aware distributions, can't any of them help you?

Comment: I am a beginner so don't have much information about CPAN verilog options,

Comment: I have pasted the full code here, please have a look at it now.@zdim

Comment: Your output is not Verilog syntax, you semicolons are incorrect. It should be `ID ID ( .ID(ID), .ID(ID), .. .ID(ID) );` I wrote a C program which does this. It is more complex then a simple perl expression, you need a real parser.

Comment: do you have an input example and desired output?

Comment: Thank you, that is much better as now people can see what you are doing. Can you also add a clear sample of typical input and the desired output for it? (What you show in the beginning is unclear.)

Comment: Notes: (1) To add to array in Perl we have: `push @code, $line;` (2) To iterate over elements of an array there is no need to involve index, but: `foreach my $elem (@ary) { ... }` (unless you need the index inside of the loop, but it seems that you don't)